# How to flatten a hierarchy from a single join table

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, mysql-5.7

I have a table that describes a hierarchical relationship with no bounds on the size. A simple example would be:

```
|ParentID |Child ID|
|1        |2       |
|2        |3       |
|1        |4       |
|5        |6       |
```

I need a query that for a given parent, gives a flat list of every child, all the way down, so for `3` it would just return `4`, but for `1` it would return `2,3,4`.

I'm coming fresh to MySQL from many years of SQL Server so am still getting used to how its more advanced query features work. There are a few examples of this on SO but they only work on hierarchies with fixed bounds on depth. I'm on MySQL 5.7 so sadly don't have CTEs.

Comment: You might like my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/20860 or my presentation https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more Googling, I came up with something based on this question: [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

```
select  distinct ChildID 
from    (select * from ParentChild) children,
        (select @ids := 1) top_level
where   find_in_set(ParentID, @ids)
and     length(@ids := concat(@ids, ',', ChildID))
```

I haven't tested it on some really large hierarchies but so far it seems to do what I want.